# Configurring Odoo in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, odoo-10

While trying to configure odoo 10 with Pycharm, I receive the following error. However running it from terminal works fine.

My openerp-server.conf file:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = admin
db_host =False
db_port =False
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
addons_path = odoo/addons,odoo/addons_st
xmlrpc_port = 8071
```

Error in Pycharm:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/odoo/workspace/odoo-10c/odoo-server -c openerp-       server.conf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/odoo/workspace/odoo-10c/odoo-server", line 2, in <module>__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace('odoo.addons')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2203, in declare_namespace
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2219, in declare_namespace
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2186, in _handle_ns
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 388, in _check_name_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 809, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 668, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/odoo/workspace/odoo-10c/odoo/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
import addons
ImportError: No module named 'addons'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your project interpretor to **python 2.5**, Odoo 10 cant run on **python 3.x.**
Python 3.x is for Odoo 11 and 11+ versions.

Comment: Fine, its a basic thing, only odoo 11 supports python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

odoo 8 support python version 2.7.16 with pip
odoo 9 also support python version 2.7
odoo 10 supports python version 2.5 and above